# i want to make pictures load when viewed?

Tags: javascript, css, html, slider, load

**Hello I Have A File That Contains A Lot Of Images I Want To Insert Them All In A Slider But I Don't Want To Make The Website Load Slow, How Can I Make Them Load When Viewed On The Slider**

Comment: i haven't tried nothing i'm still making the slider

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use the great Cycle 2 jQuery plugin and use the progressive loading option -> [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/progressive.php).